# Use "global" Thorfile

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, thor

I want to use Thor with [thor-scmversion](https://github.com/RiotGamesMinions/thor-scmversion) to bump the version of my Chef cookbooks. The normal way of using Thor is to create a `Thorfile` in the project folder and have tasks implemented in there. For my use case I would have to create a `Thorfile` in every cookbook I write containing only

```
require 'thor/scmversion'
```

My question is, whether I can somehow put such a file in a "global" directory and point to it, when I run `thor` on the command line from within my project folder.

**Edit**

I followed @coderanger's advice and used `thor install Thorfile`. This creates a directory `.thor` in the user's home directory (in my case: `/var/lib/jenkins/.thor`) and a `thor.yml` file that includes a reference to the `Thorfile` I added with the upper command.

When I now run `thor list`, I get

```
$ thor list
version
-------
thor version:bump TYPE [PRERELEASE_TYPE]  # Bump version number (type is major, minor, patch, prerelease or auto)
thor version:current                      # Show current SCM tagged version
```

but running `thor version:current`, I get the following error:

```
Could not find command "version:current".
```

So probably I missed something?

Comment: The problem described in your _Edit_ did not occur for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `thor install` to set up a system-wide task. Bear in mind this might make things more difficult for other people since it won't be set up in git for them.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me - see the edit in my question.